# Graph Depth First Search

Tags: c#

I'm trying to construct a DFS method, where a user enters the starting node and the method would display all the nodes that can be reached from that starting node.

The issue I'm facing is that my DFS method always returns the starting node.

I have used the following example in `main` method.

**GraphNode Class**

```
    public class GraphNode<T>
    {
        private T id; 
        private LinkedList<T> adjList; 

        // constructor 
        public GraphNode(T id)
        {
            this.id = id;
            adjList = new LinkedList<T>();
        }

        public T ID
        {
            get { return id; }
            set { id = value; }
        }



        public void AddEdge(GraphNode<T> to)
        {
            adjList.AddLast(to.ID);
        }

        public void RemoveEdge(GraphNode<T> to)
        {
            adjList.Remove(to.ID);
        }

        public LinkedList<T> GetAdjList()
        {
            return adjList;
        }

    }
```

**Graph Class (containing DFS method)**

```
public class Graph<T> where T : IComparable
    {

        private LinkedList<GraphNode<T>> nodes;


        public Graph()
        {
            nodes = new LinkedList<GraphNode<T>>();
        }


        public bool IsEmptyGraph()
        {
            return nodes.Count == 0;
        }

        public int NumNodesGraph()
        {
            //LinkedList<T> currentNodes;
            LinkedList<T> nodeCounterList = new LinkedList<T>();
            // to be completed
            foreach (GraphNode<T> n in nodes)
            {
                nodeCounterList.AddFirst(n.ID);
                
            }
            return nodeCounterList.Count;           

        }

        public int NumEdgesGraph()
        {
            LinkedList<T> edgeCounterList = new LinkedList<T>();
            int numberOfEdges = 0;
            foreach (GraphNode<T> n in nodes)
            {
                edgeCounterList = n.GetAdjList();
                for(int i = 0; i < edgeCounterList.Count; i++)
                {
                    numberOfEdges++;
                }
            }
            return numberOfEdges;
        }

        public bool ContainsGraph(GraphNode<T> node)
        {
            foreach (GraphNode<T> n in nodes)// iterate through all nodes in a graph
            {
                if (n.ID.CompareTo(node.ID) == 0)
                    return true;
            }

            return false;

        }

        public bool IsAdjacent(GraphNode<T> from, GraphNode<T> to)
        {
            foreach (GraphNode<T> n in nodes)
            {
                if (n.ID.CompareTo(from.ID) == 0)
                {
                    bool b = from.GetAdjList().Contains(to.ID);
                    if (b == true)
                        return true;
                }
            }
            return false;

        }

        public void AddNode(T id)
        {
            nodes.AddLast(new GraphNode<T>(id));

        }

        public GraphNode<T> GetNodeByID(T id)
        {
            foreach (GraphNode<T> n in nodes)
            {
                if (id.CompareTo(n.ID) == 0)
                {
                    return n;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        public void AddEdge(T from, T to)
        {
            GraphNode<T> n1 = GetNodeByID(from);
            GraphNode<T> n2 = GetNodeByID(to);

            if (n1 != null && n2 != null)
            {
                n1.AddEdge(n2);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Nodes not found; no edge added");
            }
        }

        public void RemoveEdge(T from, T to)
        {
            GraphNode<T> n1 = GetNodeByID(from);
            GraphNode<T> n2 = GetNodeByID(to);

            if (n1 != null && n2 != null)
            {
                n1.RemoveEdge(n2);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Nodes not found; no edge added");
            }
        }

        public void DepthFirstTraverse(T startID, ref List<T> visited)
        {
            LinkedList<T> adj;
            Stack<T> toVisit = new Stack<T>();
            GraphNode<T> current = new GraphNode<T>(startID);

            toVisit.Push(startID);
            while(toVisit.Count != 0)
            {
                current.ID = toVisit.Pop();
                visited.Add(current.ID);

                adj = current.GetAdjList();
                foreach (T n in adj)
                {
                    if (toVisit.Contains(n) == false && visited.Contains(n) == false)
                    {
                        toVisit.Push(n);
                    }
                }
               
            }

            foreach(Object s in visited)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(s + " ");
            }

        }

    }
```

**main method testing**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Graph<char> myGraph = new Graph<char>();

            myGraph.AddNode('A');
            myGraph.AddNode('B');
            myGraph.AddNode('C');
            myGraph.AddNode('D');
            myGraph.AddNode('E');
            myGraph.AddNode('F');
            myGraph.AddNode('G');

            myGraph.AddEdge('B', 'A');
            myGraph.AddEdge('A', 'C');
            myGraph.AddEdge('A', 'F');
            myGraph.AddEdge('A', 'G');
            myGraph.AddEdge('C', 'F');
            myGraph.AddEdge('C', 'D');
            myGraph.AddEdge('F', 'E');

            List<char> visited = new List<char>();

            myGraph.DepthFirstTraverse('B', ref visited);

        }
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be doing `current = GetNodeById(toVisit.Pop());` because otherwise you just set the Id and the list is empty.  Also I'd make `visted` a `HashSet<T>`

Answer (score 0):

The main problem probably is in your DFS method in which you create a new GraphNode with ID = strartID instead to theke the one that is in the graph, but this **new** node is not relative to your graph, indeed, in fact, it is a new graph
Try to replace your line `GraphNode<T> current = new GraphNode<T>(startID);` with `GraphNode<T> current = this.GetNodeByID(startID);` in this way you take the node of the graph with ID equal to startID which have some other connected nodes.
Below the fixed code:

```
public void DepthFirstTraverse(T startID, ref List<T> visited)
{
    LinkedList<T> adj;
    Stack<T> toVisit = new Stack<T>();

    GraphNode<T> current;

    toVisit.Push(startID);
    while(toVisit.Count != 0)
    {
        //OLD
        //current.ID = toVisit.Pop();
        //NEW
        current = this.GetNodeByID(toVisit.Pop());
        visited.Add(current.ID);

        adj = current.GetAdjList();
        foreach (T n in adj)
        {
            if (toVisit.Contains(n) == false && visited.Contains(n) == false)
            {
                toVisit.Push(n);
            }
        }
       
    }

    foreach(Object s in visited)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(s + " ");
    }

}
```

EDIT:

I forgot to update the current node by changing from `current.ID = toVisit.Pop();` to `current = this.GetNodeByID(toVisit.Pop());`

Comment: This would still not work because `current.Id = toVisit.Pop()` just changes the id and doesn't actually get the node related to the id and you just search the start nodes list of adjacent nodes over and over again.

Comment: You're right, thanks. I forgot to update the current node.
I've just edited the code above.
--
I've tried with two level graph and seems to work, reaching each node directly or indirectly connected to the staring one

Comment: And you really don't need the `GraphNode<T> current = this.GetNodeByID(startID);` anymore since it will search for the node at the beginning of the loop again.

Comment: @juharr Thanks for your help it worked, now I'm trying to find the mother vertex of the graph. Do have an idea of how to tackle it? I know that it's going to be a method of type generic list:  ``public List<T> mothervertex()``